# Can I fix a scratched iPhone 5 rear camera lens?

Tags: iphone, camera, scratches

In a picture I took this afternoon with my iPhone 5 I noticed a purple line on the photo:

[image: image of purple line on photo]

At first I thought it was a software issue so I rebooted the phone. Unfortunately, after a reboot the line was still there on new photographs.

Upon closer examination it appears that the rear lens of my iPhone 5 has somehow become scratched. Is there a way to fix this? Or do I need to just have the phone replaced?

Comment: Maybe late, but how did you manage to fix your problem? In the future you might check iFixit as they provide guides on how to fix Apple stuff.

Comment: @Rob ultimately it was a hair that worked it's way out: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91840/can-i-fix-a-scratched-iphone-5-rear-camera-lens?noredirect=1#comment121477_92020.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don’t do it your self at first! go to an Apple Store and let it check, maybe it’s just a hair!

Comment: It ultimately was just a hair that moved off the lens on its own.

Answer (score 2):

Well i think you can do it

Lens - http://www.witrigs.com/replacement-camera-lens-for-iphone-5

Video on **howto** do it - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Si0M3wak4Q0

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can replace the camera lens, but it is difficult. The camera lens is cheap. But it takes much time to replace the scratched one:

- Tear down the front LCD screen
- Tear down all the small parts, battery, motherboard, dock flex cable, and camera etc
- Use a heat gun to heat the camera lens, use something to make the lens out
- Use Glue to glue to new lens on the original position of the back housing

Comment: Please check out iFixit ;)